# Calling a method - Why isnt this working? - Java

Tags: java, methods

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

            getRandomPrints({"a" , "b" ,"c" , "d"});

        }

        public static void getRandomPrints(String[] args){
             System.out.printLn("Hello World" + arg")
        }
```

I am having problems calling this method, I would like to know what I am doing wrong here.
it says

```
The method getRandomPrints(String[]) in the type test is not applicable for the arguments()
```

I would like to know that whats wrong here thanks

Comment: Well, it won't compile to start with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        getRandomPrints(new String[]{"a" , "b" ,"c" , "d"});

    }

    public static void getRandomPrints(String[] args){
         System.out.println("Hello World" + args);
    }
```

There are also few compile time errors which I have fixed like `println`

Comment: It should also be pointed out that the way it stands, this will print out `Hello World[Ljava.lang.String;@1db9742`. Instead you should try something like `System.out.println("Hello World" + args[0] + args[1]...)`

Comment: @Demyx97:  It'd be better if it were `"Hello World " + Arrays.toString(args)`.  You don't know for certain how long that array is, and indexing into each is inefficient.

Comment: @Demyx97 for printing the string array is another question,just solved *getRandomPrints(String[]) in the type test is not applicable for the arguments()*

Comment: Variable length args can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing correct argument to the method:

```
getRandomPrints({"a" , "b" ,"c" , "d"});// not a valid array
```

also here are few corrections:

```
System.out.printLn("Hello World" + args);
            `l` ^            note `s` ^ ^ semicolon was missing
```

You may either try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getRandomPrints(new String[]{"a" , "b" ,"c" , "d"});//creating new array of string
}

public static void getRandomPrints(String[] args){
    for(String s : args)
       System.out.println(s);
}
```

or `varargs`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getRandomPrints("a" , "b" ,"c" , "d");
}

public static void getRandomPrints(String... args){//varargs to handle csv as array
    for(String s : args)
       System.out.println(s);
}
```

or `split()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getRandomPrints("a,b,c,d".split(","));
}

public static void getRandomPrints(String[] args){
    for(String s : args)
       System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you didn't print the raw array; use `Arrays.toString` to handle that.